# google bigquery authentication from remote server

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-bigquery

I have a python script is run from a remote server (our server). The script uses `pandas_gbq` module to perform BQ query using `pd.read_gbq(query, project , private_key)`. Using the private_key (path to json) works fine locally, but when I uploaded the script as well as the key to the server there was what seems to be authentication problem  and  I got this error:

> "raise value\ngoogle.auth.exceptions.TransportError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='accounts.google.com', port=443): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: /o/oauth2/token (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1,
>   u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify
>   failed(_ssl.c:765)')"

I guess I can try using the bigquery module instead of the pandas_gbq module and try to connect, but eventually they use the same key to I can think of a reason why it should work. Any advise will be appreciated.

Comment: From where are you running this? Some VMs include very old SSL root certificates which need to get updated, for example.

Comment: Thanks @TimSwast and anyone else who tried to help. I guess that you are on the right tack because someone else at my workplace updated SSL on that server and the problem self resolved ... I'm not entirely sure that's the reason , but it's the most parsimonious explanation ..